# boot machine using qemu

Tags: virtualization, qemu

I am trying to boot vm using qemu, the command that I use is

qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-21-generic -hda /music/1gbfile

and its giving a error : Please append a correct "root=" boot option.

What does root mean here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-21-generic -hda /music/1gbfile -append "root=/dev/hda"
```

You are basically making /dev/hda (which you provide with -hda argument) as your system's root directory. You can find more information [here](http://wiki.qemu.org/download/qemu-doc.html)